# SSIS Script Task is throwing an exception, how to view the message?

Tags: debugging, exception, ssis

SSIS is showing some useless "Target of invocation has thrown an error" along with an equally useless stack trace that shows only the invocation call. Logging is enabled.

Is there a way to view the actual exception message thrown by the package without attaching some debugger?

Answer (score 19):

Just trap the exception in a try..catch statement and use the FireError method in the catch block:

```
public void Main()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        ...
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", ex.Message, null, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `FireError` method is useful, thanks. Still a bit silly that SSIS logging can't capture the full exception message (even if it is an inner exception).

Comment: My SSIS is being super stupid. It suppresses all output once there is an error. MessageBox.Show on line 1 and I get no MessageBox. Does anyone know if there is some sort of setting like "pretend nothing ran if on error" I can't even understand why someone would want this to happen!

Comment: How am I only just now discovering `Dts.Events.FireError`? thank-you!